# Configure DropWizard to serve metrics on application HTTP connector

Tags: dropwizard

DropWizard traditionally serves metrics on an admin port such as 8081 e.g. http://localhost:8081/metrics and application resources are served on e.g. 8080. Both the port numbers are configurable and I have in the past configured them to be the same.

After the configuration structure changed in 0.7.x, how can I configure metrics to appear on the same port as the application? I don't mind whether, or not, the other stuff served on the admin port moves over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring the server type as 'simple' will allow the application and admin sites to run on the same port and HTTP connector, this should work:

```
server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /application
  adminContextPath: /admin
  connector:
    type: http
    port: 8080
```

This will cause metrics to be available at http://localhost:8080/admin/metrics. See the [Dropwizard server configuration reference](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.0/docs/manual/configuration.html#simple) for more details.